# can I disable generating alock file in OpenLDAP for bdb database?

Tags: openldap

I have taken the OpenLDAP 2.4.39 and able to run slapd  properly but when I do slapcat without stopping slapd it hangs and always complains on alock file,But if I delete alock file or disable alock generation in OpenLDAP code then it works fine.

I have 4.6.21 version of bdb,I don't know much about alock file in bdb .

Can you please suggest is it ok to disable alock file generation in the openLDAP code for running slapd and slapcat parallel ?

Thanks,
Pramod

Comment: No you can't. You have to slop slapd to run slapcat. If you remove the lock file, data integrity is compromised. Don't do this.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but in the OpenLDAP manual it is written slapcat will work when slapd process is running(without stopping slapd).I also observed sometime it works when I restart slapd 2 times but is very inconsistent.Does that mean better to use slapcat in offline mode ?

Comment: I've found that on Windows at least slapd has to be stopped before slapcat will run.

Comment: Thanks for the response,I checked with OpenLDAP tech team they told me there was a bug in alock file and fixed in latest version.

Comment: If backend is changed from BDB to MDB then slapcat works without stopping the slapd service.